# android studio 3.2 Failed to read key

Tags: android, android-keystore, jks

I tried to update android studio from 2.4 to 3.2 when I download the new version it doesn't override the old one so I have two versions of android studio on my pc when I try to generate a signed APK on 3.2 it gives Failed to read key xxxx from store but if I tried with the old version with the same key store and password it success what is the solution to success on new version

Comment: Is it already out for the stable Verisio.?

Comment: stable version you mean 2.4? if yes I can't run updated codes on this version so i need to run with 3.2 but if i open a backup project on 2.4 generation of signed APK success

Comment: Actually many things changed from 3.0 onwards.. So create a new keystore file and you are good to go.. The error will not come. Create a new keystore file using 3.2 Android studio and generate apk using this new keystore file.

Comment: I tried this option it works to generate but when I uploaded it to the store it fails since it is a different signature and note that i generated this  new one with exactly the same old informations.

Comment: What do you mean by Same old information? I did not understand that

Comment: Information needed to create new keystore like alias password firstname and last name ....country code..

Comment: Oh.. what does the error on play store say.. I don't think its the problem of the different signature.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180625/discussion-between-bob-and-umang-burman).